# I keep getting error "Error in Y %*% X : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments"

Tags: r

My code is this:

```
X2 <- list(33, 41, 7, 49, 5, 31)
Y <- list(42, 33, 75, 28, 91, 55)
X <- matrix(cbind(1:1,X1,X2),nrow=6,ncol=3)
Y <-t(X)

XtX <- X %*% Y
```

And I don't know what is going wrong pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create the matrix with vectors instead of lists:

```
X1 <- c(33, 41, 7, 49, 5, 31)
X2 <- c(42, 33, 75, 28, 91, 55)
X <- as.matrix(cbind(1:1,X1,X2),nrow=6,ncol=3)

XtX <- X %*% t(X)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] 2854 2740 3382 2794 3988 3334
[2,] 2740 2771 2763 2934 3209 3087
[3,] 3382 2763 5675 2444 6861 4343
[4,] 2794 2934 2444 3186 2794 3060
[5,] 3988 3209 6861 2794 8307 5161
[6,] 3334 3087 4343 3060 5161 3987
```

Not sure `matrix(cbind(1:1,X1,X2),nrow=6,ncol=3)` is exactly what you expect:

```
       X1 X2
[1,] 1 33 42
[2,] 1 41 33
[3,] 1  7 75
[4,] 1 49 28
[5,] 1  5 91
[6,] 1 31 55
```

Comment: see my edit regarding `cbind` : the first 1 is recycled to the length of the other columns.